# String classification, how to encode character-by-character and train?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nltk, data-science, embedding

I am trying to build a classifier to classify some files into 150 categories based on the name of those files. Here are some examples of file names in my dataset (~700k files):

```
104932489 - urgent - contract validation for xyz limited.msg
treatment - an I l - contract n°4934283 received by partner.pdf
- invoice_8843238_1_europe services_business 8592342sid paris.xls
140159498736656.txt
140159498736843.txt
fsk_000000001090296_sdiselacrusefeyre_2000912.xls
fsk_000000001091293_lidlsnd1753mdeas_2009316.xls
```

You can see that the filenames can really be anything, but that however there is always some pattern that is respected for the same categories. It can be in the numbers (that are sometimes close), in the special characters (spaces, -, °), sometimes the length, etc.

Extracting all those patterns one by one will take ages because I have approximately 700k documents. Also, I am not interested in 100% accuracy, 70% can be good enough.

The real problem is that I don't know how to encode this data. I have tried many methods:

- Tokenizing character by character and feeding them to an LSTM model with an embedding layer. However, I wasn't able to implement it and got dimension errors.
- Adapting Word2Vec to convert the characters into vectors. However, this automatically drops all punctuation and space characters, also, I lose the numeric data. Another problem is that it creates more useless dimensions: if the size is 20, I will have my data in 20 dimensions but if I look closely, there are always the same 150 vectors in those 20 dimensions so it's really useless. I could use a 2 dimensions size but still, I need the numeric data and the special characters.
- Generating n-grams from each path, in the range 1-4, then using a CountVectorizer to compute the frequencies. I checked and special characters were not dropped but it gave me like 400,000 features! I am running a dimensionality reduction using UMAP (n_components=5, metric='hellinger') but the reduction runs for 2 hours and then the kernel crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently also working on a character level lstm. And it works exactly the same like when you would use words. You need a vocabulary, for example a - z and then you just take the index of the letter as its integer representation. For example:

`"bad" -> "b", "a", "d" -> [1, 0, 3]`

Now you could create an embedding lookup table (for example using pytorchs nn.Embedding function). You just have to create a random vector for every index of your vocab. For example:

`"a" -> 0 > [-0.93, 0.024, -.0.73, ..., -0.12]`

You said that you tried this but encountered dimension errors? Maybe show us the code!

Or you could create non-random embedding using word2vec using the Gensim libary:

```py
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# 'total_words' is a list containing every word of your dataset split into its characters
total_words = [...]
model = Word2Vec(total_words , min_count=1, size=32)
model.save(save_model_file)

# lets test it for the character 'a'
embedder = Word2Vec.load(save_model_file)
v = embedder["a"]

# v now will be a the embedding vector of a with size 32x1
```

I hope I could make clear how to create embeddings for characters.
You can treat characters in single-word-classification the exact same way you would treat words in sentence-classification.